# How to merge multiple ADF files to a single shapefile?

Tags: shapefile, convert, merge, esri-coverage-format

I have a set of adf file which use the same structure. How can I merge all ADF to shp file? Does the ogr2ogr command can help in this case?

Comment: this question might be useful: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22067/how-can-i-load-adf-files-to-quantum-gis

Comment: ADF is a raster file, so conversion to shapefile is not trivial. It requeres vectorisation, can be done with SAGA: Shapes - Grid > Vectorising Grid Classes

Comment: adf is raster format! is this the Arc/Info Binary Coverage? or i did made misleading!

Answer (score 1):

The ADF file format is the Arc/Info Binary file format.  Like a SHP file, the ADF file is actually several files, that together act as one file.

ADF is also a raster file, which means you cannot convert it directly to a Shapefile without, as @warrieka suggested, first converting the raster to vector shapes.  Shapefile only supports vector data, not raster data.

If you are wanting the ADF raster data in one file you might consider converting it to something like GeoTIFF.  GeoTIFF is widely compatible and multipurpose.  But you can convert it to anything you would like or suits your needs the best.

Comment: Thanks for your explaination. I also want to know how can I merge all adf file and convert to shp. Is there any good suggestion?

Comment: You probably want to check the [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/) tool called [gdal_polygonize.py](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_polygonize.html) This will convert a raster to a shapefile.