# Loading *.adf files into QGIS using Python

Tags: qgis, python, esri-grid-format

I am trying to write a loop to load .adf files into QGIS and create a contour map from each one. The response to an older question about loading .adf files (here: [Loading *.adf files into QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22067/loading-adf-files-into-qgis)) was very good but I would like to know how to perform the same action using Python.

Comment: Not sure but as the post you linked uses the _Add Vector Layer_ menu and since [OGR](http://www.gdal.org/ogr_formats.html) supports Arc/Info Binary Coverage type files, perhaps you can try the following: `layer = QgsVectorLayer("/path/to/file.adf", "layer_name", "ogr")`.

Comment: @Joseph I tried this and got the error 'Layer is not valid'

Comment: You need to find out what the layer name is, if it is a vector "coverage". Try PAL, ARC, or CNT rather than "layer_name".  http://www.gdal.org/drv_avcbin.html  (Also, for sanity purposes please confirm that it's not a raster ADF according to the notes on that page).

Comment: It is in fact a raster file 'hdr.adf', that was the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the file was indeed a raster file 'hdr.adf'. The python script `iface.addRasterLayer(fileName, rasterName)` worked