# Opening TINs in QGIS

Tags: qgis, tin

I have created several TINs in ArcGIS and want to do further calculations on them in QGIS. For every TIN I have a folder with some `.adf-files` and one `metadata.xml` file.

If I drag and drop the folder or single files, QGIS does not recognize the data. The same happens if I go via Layer-->Add Layer.

How do I import TINs in QGIS 3.4 or 3.10?

Comment: May this help ?
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22067/loading-adf-files-into-qgis
Format description: https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000281.shtml

Comment: What version QGIS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with QGIS 3.12.0 & MDAL 4.0 (unless the milestones get changed completely), the ESRI TIN files (ADF format) will be supported through the [MDAL](https://github.com/lutraconsulting/MDAL) driver.

[MDAL GitHub ReadMe](https://github.com/lutraconsulting/MDAL#supported-formats):

> Esri TIN: Format for storing elevation data as a triangulated
>   irregular network

[MDAL Pull Request: Add support for reading arcinfo adf tin layers #162 #164](https://github.com/lutraconsulting/MDAL/pull/164):

> First Draft, the mesh seems to be loaded. Need tests to verify if the geometry is ok.

[QGIS Issue: Support for 3d visualisation of ESRI TINs #32240](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/32240):

> QGIS is going to support reading of ESRI TIN files as a mesh (through
>   MDAL) with this PR: lutraconsulting/MDAL#164 It would be great to have
>   support for 3d visualisation of the data too. QGIS 3D already supports
>   visualisation of 2dm files...

[QGIS Pull Request: [Feature][Mesh][3D] new 3D mesh layer renderer #33837](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/33837):

> This PR change the 3D mesh renderer approach The new approach is based
>   on OpenGL shader. By this way, the GPU handles rendering wireframe and
>   color ramp shading.
>
> There are two entries to render the mesh layer in the 3D view : choose
>   the mesh as terrain in the config widget activate the 3D view in the
>   layer properties. The user can choose those settings enable/disable
>   smooth triangles enable/disable wireframe choose the line width and
>   the line color of the wireframe change the verticale scale choose the
>   style of the rendering : unique color or color ramp shading settings
>   the color ramp shading as for raster layer For now, the mesh can be
>   rendered as a TIN but rendering dataset is not supported. However the
>   infrastructure is adapted for a future PR.